# TypeError: string indices must be integer

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I tried to get data from `JSON`. But instead data i get `TypeError`:

```
'TypeError: string indices must be integers'
```

Here ist my code:

```
api.authenticate(LOGIN, CONN)
profil = api.get_profile("abc")
data = json.dumps(profil, indent=4)
print(data["login"])
```

JSON file:

```
{
   "public_email": "",
   "violation_url": null,
   "is_blocked": false,
   "links_published": 0,
   "login": "abc",
   "links_added": 1,
   "gg": "",
   "signup_date": "2014-10-26 21:15:41",
}
```

I've looking for solution (google, SO) but I cannot find or not working for me.

Comment: Why are you calling `json.dumps`? That turns the data structure, which `.get_profile` has apparently created for you from the JSON, *back into a string*.

Comment: When i calling `json.loads` i getting another error. And `json.dumps` is working in another code

Comment: **What** *"another error"*? I'm saying you don't need to `json.` anything, just *use `profil`*; it appears to already be a dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

There is an extra `,` in your json file at the end. Delete this:

```
{
   "public_email": "",
   "violation_url": null,
   "is_blocked": false,
   "links_published": 0,
   "login": "abc",
   "links_added": 1,
   "gg": "",
   "signup_date": "2014-10-26 21:15:41"
}
```

Then `load` the json file (not `dump`):

```
with open('abc.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

print(data["login"])
```